# Show "Math error" to textbox when click a button with error

Tags: c#

I want to make a function in a math button when it have an error the text box will display "Math error" for example: when i click "Abs" button without number before, the text box will show "Math error" until i click a number then "Abs" button the text box will show the result. The code have no problem, i just want to add more. this first time when i click button "Abs" without number it show "Math error" that i need but when i click again it show error.

```
private void btnAbs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double abs;
        if(txtND.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            No1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtND.Text);
            abs = Math.Abs(No1);
            txtND.Text = abs.ToString();
            inputStatus = false;
        }
        if(txtND.Text == string.Empty)
        {              
                txtND.Text = "Math Error";
                inputStatus = false;                            
        }
        //inputStatus = false;
    }
```

[this is the picture of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3Oi3.png)

Comment: Post your code as text and explain what doesn't work please.

Comment: Why does everyone always post a picture of their code instead of the code itself?

Comment: Type your code and format it correctly please. Also you forgot to tell us what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert.ToDouble fail with text input, try as below

```
double dval;
double abs;
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtND.Text))
{
    txtND.Text = "Empty Input"; 
}else if (double.TryParse(txtND.Text.Trim(), out dval))
{
    abs = Math.Abs(dval);
    txtND.Text = abs.ToString();
}
else
{
    txtND.Text = "Math Error";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can verify if the textbox has been filled with a valid value and if it isn´t a valid value you can show something like MessageBox.Show("It´s not a valid value"); or after all you can show result on the messagebox as well, MessageBox.Show("The result is" + result);